# Get checked checkboxes inside an element

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

i have a `<div id="myDiv">` containing a few `<input type="checkbox">` and `<br/>`.
Now i want to loop through all elements of the div and do something if the element is a checkbox and checked. i have already tried

```
var e = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var c;
for(c in e.children){
    if(c.checked) {
        //...
    }
}
```

but `c.checked` is always undefined.
Can anyone tell me how i do that?

Comment: Jquery is allowed?

Comment: Why don't you actually select the checkboxes?

Comment: @kannan Do you see JQuery tagged in the question?

Comment: Please post the accompanying HTML.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv > input')` should help you get started. Grab all inputs under `#myDiv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go directly and target your `:checked` ones using:

```
const ckbChecked = document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv input[type=checkbox]:checked");
```

or one by one and than figuring out what to do with every respective one depending on the boolean `Element.checked` property state:

```js
const ckb = document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv input[type=checkbox]");

[...ckb].forEach( el => {

  if( el.checked ) {
    // Is checked!
    console.log( el.value )
    el.closest("label").style.background = "gold";
  } else {
    // Not checked one
    // ... do something else
    el.closest("label").style.background = "gray";
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="foo"> Foo</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="bar" checked> Bar</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="baz"> Baz</label>
</div>
```

Comment: NodeList has [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), any particular reason for the destructuring?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman Precaution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_sometimes-live_collection since it's not an actual Array. Destructuring makes it one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually select the checkboxes. Old way would be to select the inputs and check to see if they are checked, modern way, just use a selector to get the checked ones.

```js
var oldWay = document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i<oldWay.length; i++) {
  console.log(oldWay[i].checked)
}

var modernWay = document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv input:checked")
console.log(modernWay)
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />  
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />  
</div>
```

Comment: User has not asked, but it could be good idea to only loop in checkbox instead of all input

Answer (score 0):

```js
let checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')]

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  if(checkbox.checked) {
    console.log('i am checked', checkbox)
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below

```js
var matches = [];
var searchEles = document.getElementById("myDiv").children;
for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {
  var elem = searchEles[i];
  
  if (elem.type == "checkbox" && elem.checked) {
    console.log(elem.id + " is Checked");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk3">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" checked="checked">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`c` in your `for in` loop is the index of the array, that is why the checked property got undefined when you tried to access it.

Below code will work for you:

```
<div id="my-div">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
let myDiv = document.getElementById('my-div');

for (let i = 0; i < myDiv.children.length; i++) {
  console.log(myDiv.children[i]);
  if (myDiv.children[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
    console.log(myDiv.children[i].checked);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was actually really close anyway. It should have been `of` as opposed to `in`.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var c;

for (c of e.children) {
  if (c.checked) {
    console.log("winning")
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked />
</div>
```

Hope this helps